# Opacity Fade on an image, with CSS3 or JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way with Javascript or CSS3 to have the left and right side of an image fade out into the background.

Comment: This might be able to help you out. http://www.xhtml-lab.com/css/create-reflection-effect-using-css3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overlay a PNG image over your image to get the desired effect. IE does not render partially transparent PNG images properly. For this browser you need some workaround e.g. [IE PNG Fix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/).

## [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/gYjRS/)

In modern browsers, you can use CSS3 `box-shadow` property for this purpose.

## [CSS3 demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/HCssV/)

Comment: You'd only need PNGFix for IE6. All other versions of IE render transparecncy in PNGs fine.

Comment: I am not entirely sure. Some say 32-bit PNG support is still broken on IE7 (see [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Web_browser_support_for_PNG))

Comment: IE7 and up are fine. However, does have problems when animating or fading transparent PNGS. It makes the non-opaque pixels black or gray. Very annoying.

Comment: This would work for me if the background was one solid color, unfortunately it is not

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="position:relative;height:100px;width:100px">
    <div style="position:absolute;z-index:2;width:100%;height:100%;-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #fff;-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #fff;box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #fff;"></div>
    <img style="position:absolute;z-index:1"src="images/my100.png"></img>
</div>
```

This caused a white fade to be on all sides.  Check out some box shadows here css http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/

Comment: This is not supported by IE 8 or lower.  And does not give you a lot of control, but it is the only css thing i could think of.  The code is kind of sloppy, but i am sure you could fix it up.  I usually do not like to use inline styles, for they are not very scalable...

Comment: Ahh... how could I forget box-shadow?

Comment: This does not necessarily allow this to "fade into the background."  If you have a defined background color (most places seem too) you could match the shadow with the background color.  This works, but there are going to be better ways using png fades.  The cons to my solution and to the img fades is that clicks are still going to have to be transferred from one to the next... annoying

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would fit for you, but if you had a solid background colour you could fade up a .png file that fades to transparent in the middle and solid colour at the edges over the top of your image, so it looks like it is fading into the background.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left 90%, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
```

That can be used on the element directly or a parent element and still affect the children.  It's great! Only works with webkit.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so any such effect is available in `jQuery` or `jQuery UI`. You will have to try third party plugins if you are going for `JavaScript` solution.

I think it is possible through `Css` but not sure about cross browser support for this feature.